# Can't bind moment js datepicker inside a nested angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

i tried the following code to bind moment js datepicker inside angular ng-repeat text box.but it not working any one have a solution for this problem kindly give me

```js
angular.forEach(a, function(value, key) {
      debugger;
      angular.forEach(value.manageSampleBOList, function(value1, key2) {
        // var isoDate = new Date(value1.ColectedDate).toISOString();
        //   var e = moment(value1.ColectedDate);
        var date = new Date(value1.ColectedDate);

        var e = toUTCDate(new Date(value1.ColectedDate));
        //   var now_utc = new Date(e.getUTCFullYear(), e.getUTCMonth(), e.getUTCDate(), e.getUTCHours(), e.getUTCMinutes(), e.getUTCSeconds());
        //var e = moment(value1.ColectedDate);


        value.manageSampleBOList[key2].ColectedDate = e;

        //value.manageSampleBOList[key2].momentDate = moment(value1.ColectedDate);

      });
```

```html
<tr ng-repeat="TestName in ManageSampl.manageSampleBOList">
  <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="TestName.Selected"></td>
  <td>{{TestName.AnalyteName}}({{TestName.OrderCode}})</td>
  <td>
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Select a Date Time..." moment-picker="TestName.ColectedDate" locale={{Locale}} ng-model="TestName.ColectedDate" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }">

  </td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular repeat index to assign unique id to controls.
like

```
<input id="{{'listDates_' + $index}}" class="input-group-sm" moment-picker 
ng-model="listItem.inputDate"                                                                                     
locale="en" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" />
```

then you can get the value in your JS like,

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.myList.length; i++)
{
   $scope.myModel.inputDate[i] = $scope.myList.inputDate;
}
```